# How to create user sessions with Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I developed a backend API in Rails and I want to connect it to a frontend Polymer SPA. Obviously, I will need to create user sessions, so what are my options to achieve this with polymer (if someone can redirect me to example, I would be thankful)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sessions in polymer'. Sessions, generally speaking are done on the server. If you're looking some sort of persistent client side user info, look into either single building a single page app, or using cookies for simple data. .

Answer (score 1):

Possible way to do this is using kind of authentication token. You will need server side script to provide you a authentication token if you send a user name or password through Ajax. Or even you can use OAuth too which will give you access token for authenticated request. This token you can store at cookies or local storage then use it for all authenticated request.

This article might could explain more https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication

Answer (score 0):

*Works in Polymer starter kit 4 May 2016.*

In app.js (using the polymer starter kit), add a variable:

```
app.session = {};
```

Now, every time you login, you simply update app.session, and empty it on logout. It's easier than you think :)

```
app.session = ajaxResponse.userObject; //now logged in!
app.session = {};                      //now logged out!
```

To access your session in index.html simply use session.property wrapped in curly brackets:

```
<h1>My user name is {{ session.username }}</h1>
```